# ACCESS/VBA: Insert Into with autonumbering field returns annoying warning

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Ok, here's the situation
Let's have Table1(A,B,C)
A is an autonumbering field.

I'm feeding the table via vba.
Since A is autonumbering, I'm ignoring it like so:

```
SQL = INSERT INTO TABLE1(B,C) VALUES ('something','something else')
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

This works ok, access gives me a 1st warning that I'll be creating a new row.
Which is ok to me. However just after that I get this:

> Microsoft Access can't add all the records in the update or append query.
>   It set 1 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure.
>    blahblahblah click ok to run the query anyway

Which doesn't prevent it from working if I click ok, but I don't want my user to see
that warning.
And anyway why does it pop up ? Isn't it normal to leave the autonumbering field blank ?
Is there another procedure I don't know about ? What am I missing ?

I looked around google and here but couldn't find an answer :/

(I don't want to setwarnings to false since I want the first warning of adding a field and any other eventual error to be visible.)

Comment: I would use CurrentDB.Execute SQL, DBSEECHANGES + DBFAILONERROR

Comment: dbSeeChanges is only necessary if you're using an ODBC server database as your back end, e.g., SQL Server. If the back end is Jet/ACE, it serves no purpose (though I don't think it causes any harm, so you might use it for forward compatibility). I'm also not sure it's necessary for DML statements, i.e., SQL statements that return no records.

Comment: What are the data types on fields B and C? If they are not both text or memo, it's going to fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Microsoft Access can't add all the records in the update or append query.
It set 1 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure.**

That error has nothing to do with your autonumber field.  Check the data types of fields B and C.

In this example, field C is set to number, so I get the same error as you, and the INSERT succeeds but with Null in field C:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO TABLE1(B,C) VALUES ('something','something else')"
```

However, inserting a numeric value into field C works fine.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO TABLE1(B,C) VALUES ('something',99)"
```

**Edit**: This one also works in spite of supplying a text value for field C.  The difference is the text value is one the database engine can convert to a valid number:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO TABLE1(B,C) VALUES ('something','27')"
```

Comment: Implicit data type conversion is something one should avoid whenever possible, in my opinion, but it's a good point.

Comment: Ha, I'm kind of ashamed now. I was converting a checkbox to a boolean value to fill a yes/no field. Tried by directly putting the value of the checkbox, now it works ...

Answer (score 2):

Is it clearly due to the autonumbering field? Once the record is added (running the query clicking on 'run anyway'), only the autonumber field is blank?

This error shouldn't be happening for Autonumber; at least, I've never seen it before.

Comment: Well the thing is, once I override the error and tell access to run the query anyway, everything is fine: I don't get any null value and the autonumber worked. So I don't know where this comes from...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are passing in an empty string to one of the values and it's setting that column to NULL.

When you say

> Which doesn't prevent it from working
>   if I click ok

Do all of the fields get populated correctly? Including the Autonumber?

Comment: yes they do. but indeed one of the fields is left blank (string field filled with ''). Isn't '' (two single quotes) a valid string ? I'll give it a look.

Comment: filled the empty field in my form with some data, still raises the exact same error (don't have any other empty fields).